# ¿Alguien conoce este tipo de identificación de puerto? C++

Tags: c++, socket, plugin, port

Este código en C++ es parte de un plugin que envía información por puerto serie (USB). Me gustaría saber qué tipo de identifiación son estos puertos, por favor. Y cómo saber identificar los puerto de mi PC en este tipo de nomenclatura para poder cambiarlos.

```
//UDP config
unsigned short fromPort = 9092;
unsigned short Port = 9092;
unsigned short toPort = 9091;
unsigned short totelemetrtyPort = 44935;

//string HIL_IP
string HIL_IP = "192.168.7.2";
string TELEMETRY_IP = "10.100.206.5";
UDPSocket sockHIL(fromPort);
```

Comment: Intentar averiguar lo que significa un número, solo por el nombre de la variable ... A simple vista, son simples, vulgares y mundanos [puertos de red](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Puertos_de_red) y [direcciones IP](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direcci%C3%B3n_IP).

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Sé que son puertos de red, pero en Arduino estaba acostumbrado a verlo como COM4 etc. En el enlace ajunto hay muchos que no conocía, pero por desgracia no aparacen los míos. Gracias por tu tiempo! :)

Comment: **No confundas** puertos de red con **pines Arduino**. No tienen absolutamente nada que ver. Vamos, el día y la noche se parecen mas.

Comment: Perdón, me expliqué mal. Me refería el puerto usb que detecta el ordenador cuando enchufas un arduino. O mirado desde el administrador de dispositivos de windows cualquier USB que enchufes te aparece allí como COMX. De aquí mi confusión con un número como 9092 que se llama aquí.

Comment: La explicacion de wikipedia es muy pobre. En forma muy sencilla (y no correcta): una PC tiene una direccion IP, y cada programa dentro de ella tiene un puerto. De esa manera, cuando me quiero conectar a un programa dentro de otra PC, tengo que establecer una conexion a una IP+Puerto.